# Dropdown menu doesn`t have highlights when page resize . i used bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, dropdown

Dropdown menu does not have highlight when i resize my page. Here is my Css code.

```
 .dropdown-submenu {
position: relative;
 }

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
top: 0;
left: 100%;
margin-top: -6px;
margin-left: -1px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

 .dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
display: block;
 }

 .dropdown-submenu>a:after {
display: block;
content: " ";
float: right;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-color: transparent;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
border-left-color: #ccc;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-right: -10px;
 }

 .dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
 border-left-color: #fff;
 }

 .dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
float: none;
 }

 .dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
left: -100%;
margin-left: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;

 }  

  .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
        background-color:red;

    }
```

Look at the image.. when the size of the page is bigger it have a red highlight but when the size of the page is smaller (right side picture) it doesn`t have a red highlight

[image: My sample image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `!important`:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, 
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```